# DateTimeFormatter - parsing string with time zone

Tags: java, time

I have a JSpinner for selecting specific time (with today's date) and I need to convrert the String result into `LocalDateTime` instance. However, I can't seem to write the regex string right. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

JSpinner:

```
        SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        spinnerStart = new JSpinner(sm);
        JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinnerStart, "hh:mm");
        spinnerStart.setEditor(de);
```

When checking the value with `spinnerStart.getValue().toString()`, I get the following:

```
Mon May 25 12:21:24 CEST 2015
```

I am trying to parse the string according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation but am getting an exception:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=21, MilliOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=0, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=24},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 2015-05-25 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
```

This is my progress so far:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse(spinnerStart.getValue().toString(), dtf);
```

I tried using 'V' instead of 'z' and some other choices with offsets as well but cannot seem to figure it out. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You know you could use `(Date)spinnerStart.getValue()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have a `java.util.Date` object, which represents a precise instant on the time-line. And to transform it into a LocalDateTime, you're transforming the Date into a String, and then parse the String.

That's a bad strategy. You shouldn't do that.

Just use the date transformation methods:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = 
    date.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDateTime();
```

Of course, if you want the value for another time zone than the default one, you'll need to pass the appropriate ZoneId.